# Where can I find my project file when publishing a local azure function?

Tags: azure-functions, kudu, azure-functions-core-tools

I'm new to azure function, and I'm working on a project where I used some local data (in .json format); locally, I can access to the file that contains the JSON data by simply using a path such as "D:/projectname/JsonFile" but when I published the project to Azure platform, Obviously the path has become incorrect, so in this case I need to know where can I find the file to set the path. I've searched under "D:\home\site\wwwroot" in Kudu and I couldn't find it !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deploy your function to azure with Visual Studio, you need to set .json file property `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy always`. Then it will appear under `D:\home\site\wwwroot` in KUDU.

[image]

[image]